# Command raised an exception: OperationalError: near "<": syntax error sqlite3 discord.py

Tags: mysql, sqlite, mysql-python

```
            cursor.execute(f"UPDATE blackasjackas SET pirmas_korta = {pirmas_korta} WHERE userid={ctx.author.id}")
```

I'm having a problem with this line, it's giving me the operationalerror near "<" and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it

pirmas_korta returns a string "<:2H:804013503354634280>"

Comment: Does the `pirmas_korta` column really support UTF-8 Emoji characters?  You have some encoding problem going on here.

Comment: it's not saving as an emoji, just as the string "<:2H:804013503354634280>", I edited the post, sorry for not clarifying that it's a string, not a whole emoji

Comment: Consider not using format strings for SQL statements btw, this is dangerous for possible SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python specialist, but SQL-standart requires strings to be apostrophed, so since pirmas_korta is some kind of a string value, update statement should look like the following

```
f"UPDATE blackasjackas SET pirmas_korta = '{pirmas_korta}' WHERE userid={ctx.author.id}"
```

Comment: yes, I fixed it like 5 minutes ago, but thank you